# Firebase Cloud Function Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: typescript, sendgrid-api-v3

I have a Firebase Cloud function written in JavaScript that I want to convert to TypeScript but the request.body is giving a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Here is a snippet of the function in index.js that is working

```
exports.sendgridwebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const body = req.body; //body is an array of JavaScript objects
  functions.logger.log("Webhook Event Body", body)

  body.forEach(elem => {
    const event = elem.event;
    functions.logger.log("Event: ", event)
  });
  return res.status(200).end();

})
```

And the same code snippet in index.ts gives an error

```
export const sendgridwebhook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const body: = request.body;
  functions.logger.log("Webhook Event Body", body);

  body.forEach((element) => {
      const event = element.event;
      functions.logger.log("Event: ", event);
    });
  return res.status(200).end();
});
```

I have tried casting the body to `const body: Array<any> = request.body;` and also `const body: Array<unknown> = request.body;` without success.

So how can I update a TypeScript type to be inferred at runtime like JavaScript?

Here is the content of the body
[image: Content of Body]

Comment: `//body is an array of JavaScript objects` -- *Are you sure?*  The error message says that `body` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, the SendGrid API doc says its a JSON array and when I run the index.js version I do get an array.

Comment: what do you see in your log functions.logger.log("Webhook Event Body", body) ?

Comment: If Javascript is saying that `body` is undefined, I'm pretty sure there's no array in there.

Comment: @NadhirFalta I have added a screenshot of the body

Comment: Side note: You should adapt `return res.status(200).end();`to `return response.status(200).end();`